# Evaluate this integral without using the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I want to evaluate this integral

$$ I = \int_c \tan z + \frac{\csc z}{z} dz $$
$$ c :|z| = 1 $$

apparently tanz is analytic in this region so its integral equals to zero 
now 
$$ I = \int_c\frac{\csc z}{z} dz $$
okay I did the following

$$ \frac{\csc z}{z} = \frac{1}{z\sin z} =\frac{1}{z(z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\cdots)}  $$

$$ \frac{\csc z}{z} = \frac{1}{z^2(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\cdots)} $$

letting 
$$  g(z) = \frac{1}{(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\cdots)} $$
then

$$ \frac{\csc z}{z} = \frac{g(z)}{z^2} $$

$$ I = \int_c\frac{\csc z}{z} dz = \int_c\frac{g(z)}{z^2} dz  $$

using cauchy's integral formula for derivatives 
$$ \int_c\frac{g(z)}{z^2} dz = \frac{2\pi i }{1!}  g'(0) $$

well $$ g'(0) = 0 $$ 
and the whole integral equals to zero this means the function is analytic which doesn't seem to be true did I make a mistake?

Comment: The integral being zero doesn't mean the function is analytic.  For example, $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^2} = 0$ but $1/z^2$ definitely isn't analytic at $z=0$.

Comment: Morera's theorem states that if an integral over a closed contour equals to zero then the function is analytic inside and on the contour

Comment: Morera's theorem states that if an integral over EVERY closed contour in some domain equals to zero then the function is analytic on that domain.  You're only looking at the integral over one single contour.

Comment: Yes right. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $\tan$ is only analytic away from its poles, but there aren't any inside the unit circle. Second, you would need to know $\int_C g(z)\,dz=0$ with $g$ continuous and for all circles $C$ to conclude $g$ is analytic.

One shortcut for you: $(\csc z)/z$ is an even function, so, without computation, its residue at $0$ must be $0$.